How to render components exported from mdx in Astrojs?
I got a mdx file like this and I want to render the foo component in somewhere else.
---
title: Hi, World!
---

export const title = 'My first MDX post'
export const foo = <h1>adsf</h1>

# {title}


by
---
const matches = await Astro.glob('../../content/blog/*.mdx');

const foo = matches[0].foo
---


I got
{
  'astro:jsx': true,
  type: 'h1',
  props: { children: "adsf" },
  [Symbol(astro:renderer)]: 'astro:jsx'
}

Is it possible to render it in .astro? both {foo} and <foo/> not works

have you tried const foo = await matches[0].foo.render()

matches[0].foo.render is not a function
it doesn't have this method

how about const foo = await matches[0].render()

Can you put the Foo component in a separate file like Foo.astro and import it in Mdx file and in a Astro file?
